# Is there any easy way to compare list items in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have:

```
x= [2,2,2,2]
y= [2,1,2,2]
```

is there any neat way to check if the list item are all equal or not. So, I want the out put as:

```
x True
y False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use `set`:

```
>>> len(set(x)) == 1
True
>>> len(set(y)) == 1
False
```

Use the following script to see, which works fastest for you:

```
from timeit import timeit

# All the same
print timeit('len(set([2, 2, 2, 2])) == 1')
# 0.843292317054

# Not the same
print timeit('len(set([2, 1, 2, 2])) == 1')
# 0.869108628247

## Without set ##

# AlL the same
print timeit('all(item == x[0] for item in x)', setup='x = [2,2,2,2]')
# 1.20339177387

# Not the same
print timeit('all(item == x[0] for item in x)', setup='x = [2, 1, 2, 2]')
# 1.42827283125
```

From my experience, using `set` seems to be the fastest way.

Comment: Was about to post this.. +1 :D

Comment: Well, that performance comparison is interesting and counterintuitive. But try it with longer lists -- the `set` solution has to lose out at some point, as it's in a different complexity class.

Comment: @svk I am in agreement with that, I told steve so too. But for tiny lists, this seems to be faster. I think steve's answer would be faster if he'd used `operator`.

Comment: I think it's the generator overhead. This is even faster than `set` for me: `print timeit('all_same(x)', setup = 'x = [2,2,2,2]\n\ndef all_same(xs):\n  if not xs: return False\n  for x in xs:\n    if x != xs[0]: return False\n  return True\n\n' )`

Comment: It's especially counterintuitive that `all` is faster in the case you'd expect to be slower, of all being equal. I suppose there's some constant overhead to exiting early, that in this case is higher than doing the remaining two comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

If you care a bit about performance and the lists might be long:

```
all(item == x[0] for item in x)
```

This completes as soon as it finds a non-equal element. Be aware that `all` returns `True` for an empty sequence, so if that's not the result you want then test `len(x)` first.

Timings, for a case deliberately rigged to favour my answer:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5

$ python -mtimeit "x = range(1000000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 18 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "x = range(1000000); all(item == x[0] for item in x)"
100 loops, best of 3: 19.2 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "x = range(1000000); all(item == x[0] for item in x[1:])"
10 loops, best of 3: 35.6 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "x = range(1000000); len(set(x)) == 1"
10 loops, best of 3: 72.7 msec per loop
```

By caring "a bit", I just mean taking easy steps to avoid possible large amounts of unneeded work and memory use. If you care a *lot* about performance, because this line of code is really critical, then there's bound to be something you can do to tweak my answer. The first thing that springs to mind is avoiding the self-comparison at element 0, but I don't know whether `itertools.islice` has low enough overhead to be a net win. You'd have to test it.

Comment: Why bother checking for an empty list?

Comment: @Tim: because I stupidly thought that I would otherwise use `x[0]` out of bounds! Thanks.

Comment: The check alters the result for the empty list, from being equivalent to `len(set(x)) == 1` with it to `len(set(x)) <= 1` without it. Admittedly the question doesn't really specify which is desired.

Comment: @svk: good point. Whatever the correct result is for an empty list, one of the two answers will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: So something like `(len(x) < 2) || all(i == x[0] for i in x[1:])`

Comment: @Useless: nominally `x[1:]` creates a copy, so unless it's cleverly optimized when it appears in this context I'd say no.

Comment: @SteveJessop Take a look at my answer, It seems that your claim seems to be wrong.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: true, I was talking about performance for non-tiny lists.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: but if the questioner is doing lots and lots of comparisons on tiny lists, your answer would win.

Comment: Yep, I'd assumed slicing was fairly cheap but my intuition was clearly wrong. The comparison would have to be _very_ expensive to outweigh the allocation

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned performance and got into this issue in the first place :-) The reason that I'd use `all` *is* because of performance for big inputs, but I don't know whether the questioner requires big inputs. It's not premature optimization to write code based on your own ideas of what operations to avoid, it probably is premature optimization to write code based on someone else's who hasn't seen the real use-case. And it would even be pessimization to use `all` if the inputs are known to be small, as shown by Games Brainiac.

Comment: @SteveJessop You and me, war of the `timeit`s :P

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to convert the list to a set, and check the length of the set:

```
def has_only_one_element(xs):
    return len(set(xs)) == 1
```

Comment: What? This seems to do something completely different.

Comment: Looks correct to me. The downside is that it might do a lot more work (and use more memory) that necessary.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yeah, I mis-understood the question. Downvote removed.

Comment: @unwind How so? `has_only_one_element(x)` is `True` and `has_only_one_element(y)` is `False`, as requested, right? Of course, Steve Jessop's answer is more efficient.

Comment: @svk I mis-understood the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function works for you...

```
def chk_similar_ele(inp_list):
   return inp_list.count(inp_list[0]) == len(inp_list)
```